# Cordova run test in browser with cmd line or gulp

Tags: cordova, gulp

I want to make a gulp task that will help me debug my cordova app in the browser while the plugins like `device` fire `deviceready` event.

I used `cordova platform add browser` and then run the app with `cordova run browser --target chrome`. But the problem is that the `deviceready` event does not fire at all.

What options could I be missing? And is there a way to make a gulp task that will run the whole browser simulation setup like in Visual Studio Code. (what i'm talking about is shown this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ63i.png) )

Answer (score 1):

mac command for run apk and make builcordova run android

Comment: cordova run android

Comment: cordova run ios